# Can you set the column of a dataframe to be a reference of another column in the same dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I don't know if this can be done.

For context, I have a dataframe `df`, with columns `modified` and `unmodified`. Depending on an user input flag, `use_modified`, I may want to use a modified or unmodified column to do some computations. The computations occur in a loop, so I don't want to do something like

```
for i in len(df):
  if use_modified:
    # use df["modified"][i] to do some computations
  else:
     # use df["unmodified"][i] to do some computations
```

I would like to create a 3rd column "value_to_use" that's a reference to either `modified` or `unmodified` depending on the flag `use_modified`, and then the loop doesn't have to do if checks.

Comment: What kind of computations?

Comment: @Corralien Just some basic algebra computations that depend on either modified/unmodified column values and some other values in other columns (not shown in OP)

Comment: Computations are the same for both columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an intermediate variable:

```
col = 'modified' if use_modified else 'unmodified'

for i in range(len(df)):
    df[col][i]
```

but you should use vectorized functions instead of iterate on each row.

Answer (score 0):

`for i in len(df):` - usually it is highly discouraged to simply iterate over the dataframe rows due to subpar performance compared to [vectorized](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/pandas-vectorization/) operations.

As for the question - you can define a variable holding the column name and use it in computations:

```py
column_to_use = "modified" if use_modified else "unmodified"

# use df[column_to_use]
for i in range(len(df)):
  i = df[column_to_use][i]
```

Comment: `for i in len(df)` is not iterable. Use `range(len(df))` or `df.iterrows()` or something else :)

Comment: This is what I have done currently, but I wanted to avoid changing the API of the function that does the computations (I'd need to pass in `use_modified`). 

As for the for loop, it's because for each row in the `df`, we compute something and then `yield` something, so I think we lose the ability to vectorize

Comment: @Corralien yes, I know that is why `...`. Updated code, thank you! =)